# Multiplication of two-dimensional and three-dimensional tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorly

There is a two dimensional tensor `a[m,n]`, and a three dimensional tensor `b[k,n,h]`. What API should I use to multiply two dimensional tensors by three dimensional tensors to get a three dimensional tensor `c[k,m,h]`?

Actually I can got it by:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorly as tl
x = tf.constant([[[1,2],[3,7],[8,9]],
                 [[4,5],[6,10],[11,12]]],tf.float32)
a = tf.constant([[-0.70711,0.57735],
                 [0.0000,0.57735],
                 [0.70711,0.57735]])
reshape_A = tf.reshape(x, [2,6])

re = tf.reshape(tf.matmul(a, reshape_A), [3, 3, 2])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(re))
    re = re.eval()
```

But is there an easier way?

Comment: The example you gave does not fit your description. Your `a` is `(3,2)`, but your `x` is `(2,3,2)`. And `tf.matmul` supports batch multiply so that you can expand `a` to `(k,m,n)` multiply by `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tensorly.tenalg.contract](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.tenalg.contract.html#tensorly.tenalg.contract).
For your example:

```
import tensorly as tl
import numpy as np
tl.set_backend('tensorflow')

k = 2; m = 3; n = 5; h = 4

A = tl.tensor(np.random.random((m, n)))
B = tl.tensor(np.random.random((k, n, h)))

res = tl.tenalg.contract(A, 1, B, 1)
```